# Devo parar a aplicação quando rodo um teste

Tags: java

Atualmente tenho minha aplicação em produção e preciso criar alguns testes (Junit). Minha dúvida é se preciso parar a aplicação ou posso rodar o teste direto.

Alguém já passou ou sabe algo sobre isso?

Comment: Acredito que você ainda não entendeu o conceito de Testes. Recomendo a leitura do artigo: https://www.devmedia.com.br/junit-tutorial/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua pergunta nem mesmo tem sentido. Rodar testes JUnit não tem nada a ver sobre rodar em produção.

Os testes do JUnit meio que são uma extensão do processo de compilação. Você compila o seu projeto e executa os testes. Se os testes pegarem algo errado, o processo de construção é cortado com um status de erro (embora você possa escolher, de forma seletiva, por deixá-lo passar mesmo se alguns testes específicos falharem). Note que esse processo é efetuado na máquina do desenvolvedor.

Num processo de desenvolvimento maduro, quando os testes passarem, você pega o JAR/WAR/EAR/etc produzido e coloca em produção. Mas nada te impede de fazer o mesmo com um JAR/WAR/EAR/etc que não tenha sido testado com o JUnit (não é boa ideia, mas você pode se quiser).

Executar testes do JUnit em produção é algo que não existe e nem faz qualquer sentido vez que o JUnit roda os testes na máquina do desenvolvedor, e não em produção.

Quanto a parar uma aplicação em produção por causa de testes no JUnit, isso faz menos sentido ainda, vez que as duas coisas estão rodando em máquinas diferentes. E mesmo se for em uma mesma máquina, isso seria o mesmo que querer parar a aplicação em produção para rodar o compilador (ou seja, bobagem).

Comment: Acontece que, a aplicação já está rodando em produção e estou fazendo algumas manutenções, então criei alguns testes para depois subir as alterações. Aí fiquei em dúvida quanto a isso, se seria necessário para a aplicação ou não. Mas tua resposta deu uma luz, valeu mesmo!

Answer (score 1):

Você deveria realizar os testes **Antes** de enviar o código para produção.

Idealmente, existe um ambiente de homologação para realização dos testes, e se esses passarem, então somente ai você envia os códigos para o ambiente de produção. É importante ter em mente que quanto mais atômicos forem suas classes e métodos, mais desacoplado seu código será e menor é a chance de ocorrer algum problema durante os testes, já que uma modificação não costuma resultar em uma cascata de reações.

Não existe isso de testar um código que já está em produção. Caso não exista um ambiente de homologação, os testes podem ser realizados na própria máquina utilizada para o desenvolvimento antes do envio do código, tendo em mente que o ambiente de testes pode ser diferente do que o de produção. Se não estiver aplicando o processo de integração contínua, sugiro altamente que faça uma leitura sobre o tema para utilização em seu ciclo de trabalho.